# Python Argparse: how to make an argument required if and only if one flag is given?

Tags: python, python-3.x, arguments, argparse

I am wondering how can I make one argument required when one flag is given, and optional when that flag is not given?

```
import argparse


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('-c', '--convert', action = 'store_true')
parser.add_argument('-l', '--lookup', action = 'store_true')
parser.add_argument('name', type = str) 

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.name:
    print(args.name)
if args.convert:
    print ("convert now!")
```

For example, in the codes above, I want `name` to be required, only when `-c` is given. When I run the program only with `-l`, then there is an error:

```
$ python3 test.py -l
usage: test.py [-h] [-c] [-l] name
test.py: error: the following arguments are required: name
```

I have tried to use argument group to divide the arguments into two groups 1. `-c` and `name`; 2. `-l`, but it didn't really work.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't anything in `argparse` to do this directly; but it can be approximated in various ways

```
parser.add_argument('-c', '--convert', action = 'store_true')
parser.add_argument('-l', '--lookup', action = 'store_true')
parser.add_argument('name', nargs='?', default='good default')
```

It's not required in either case, but in the case of `-c` you could either use the `good default`, or you can complain after parsing.

```
parser.add_argument('-c', '--convert')
parser.add_argument('-l', '--lookup', nargs='?', default='adefault', const='aconst')
```

In this case, `-c` expects an argument, your required `name`.  An argument is optional for `-l`.  If no `-l`, the value is the `default`; if  `-l` without the argument, the value is the `const`.  You could even put `-c` and `-l` in a mutually exclusive group.

There isn't a mechanism for requiring several arguments to go together (i.e. no 'mutually-required-group`).  However subparsers work along that line.  Do I need to illustrate how subparsers could be use here?

Custom Actions classes can be used to force some sort of interaction between arguments, but usually it's easier to implement that sort of thing after parsing.  Remember `argparse` allows you give arguments in any order.  Thus the `name`  positional could occur before `-c`, or after, or between `-l` and `-c` etc.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, it helps a lot! I can go to learn subparsers on my own:)

Answer (score 3):

This isn't something `argparse` can enforce on its own. What you can do is define `name` to be optional, then check after parsing if your constraint is met.

```
import argparse


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('-c', '--convert', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('-l', '--lookup', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('name', nargs='?') 

args = parser.parse_args()

# If args.name must be a non-empty string when given,
# you can use 'not args.name' in place of 'args.name is None'
if args.convert and args.name is None:
    parser.error("<name> required with --convert")

if args.name:
    print(args.name)
if args.convert:
    print ("convert now!")
```

Comment: Thanks, got it now. It is smart to use `parser.error` here!